# Can apache DocumentRoot change perl @INC?

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi

I noticed that if I change `DocumentRoot` in my VirtualHost apache2 configuration perl `@INC` is also changed from

```
/opt/perl/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/x86_64-linux 
/opt/perl/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0 
/opt/perl/lib/perl5/5.28.0/x86_64-linux 
/opt/perl/lib/perl5/5.28.0
```

to

```
/var/www_local/WWWHub 
/var/www_local/WWWHub/work
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/
/Usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 
/usr/share/perl5 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 
/usr/share/perl/5.22 
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

So if CGI script has CPAN module dependencies it wouldn't run correctly.

Why it could happen ?

Comment: Looks like you have two Perl installations on your server, i.e. changing the `DocumentRoot` changed the Perl binary the CGI script was executed with. My educated guess would be that you have Perl 5.28.1 installed as `/opt/perl/bin/perl` and Perl 5.22.1 installed as `/usr/bin/perl`.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have two different problems.

**You are using your build of Perl 5.28.0 when you want to use your build of Perl 5.22.1.**

To fix this, adjust the shebang (`#!`) line of the script to reference the correct build of Perl.

For example, you might be using

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl
```

and what you might want to be using is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

**You wish to locate modules installed in a position relative to the script.**

The script should use `use lib` and a path relative to `$RealBin` for that.

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin, "$RealBin/work";
```

(I'm assuming the script is in `/var/www_local/WWWHub`.)